# dplyr filter selects correct rows, but filter_ doesn't

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Simple data frame:

```
df=data.frame(rpm=c(3000,4000,5000))
```

the `dplyr` `filter` command works fine:

```
> filter(df, rpm == 3000)
   rpm
1 3000
```

However, I want to use the `filter_` version, because I'm told it's safer in functions. If it weren't for this, I would have just stuck with `subset`. Here's what happens:

```
> filter_(df, "rpm" == 3000)
[1] rpm
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Definitely not working. What's happening?

Comment: read [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)

Comment: `filter_(df, "rpm == 3000")`

Comment: quoting arguments in SE form is usually best done with `~` as in `filter_(df, ~rpm == 3000)`

Comment: Hmmm...it's complicated.

Comment: @StephenHenderson, I agree with you. Your suggestion works, and I would be inclined to accept your answer (in case you post it as an answer :) My only doubt is that the other answers are so much more complicated, that I wonder if there are any issues with your suggestion. Maybe I should stick with base `R`.

Comment: @DeltaIV Its worth persisting with `dplyr` and `magrittr`, `tidyr`, etc. The complexity is really only if you try to build adaptable functions upon them. Question is on hold as duplicate - so I cannot add as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can try with `interp`

```
library(layzeval)
df %>%
     filter_(interp(~ nm==3000, nm=as.name("rpm")))
#   rpm
#1 3000
```

Comment: is this the way I am supposed to use `dplyr`, inside a function? This is much more complicated and unreadable than simply `df[df$rpm==3000,]`. If this is the supposed simplification that  `dplyr` should bring in my programs, I'm definitely scrapping it in favor of base `R`.